# Who do Kiba and Tenten marry?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

Who does Kiba marry?

[image: image of Kiba]

Who does Tenten marry?

I've searched so many times and I'm still confused about this.

Comment: Kiba x Tamaki (Uchiha cat girl) ,

Tenten x Rock Lee

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear until now whom Tenten and Kiba get married to.

*If* you have seen the episode where Kiba and Shino go to collect the honey wine, they meet a girl. That girl is a ninja cat user. They are seen together in the *Boruto* movie also. It can be said that they are together.

Whether Tenten is married or not, it is still unclear.

[image: Kiba with ninja cat user]